# What kind of math is introduced in this answer related to DSP?

Tags: math

What kind of math is introduced in this answer:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/40225/30897

It smells like *standard linear algebra course* (which I haven't studied, yet), but is it only that?
Thanks!

Comment: Introduction to Digital Communications would probably be the most fitting. CDMA is a digital comms concept (chips, orthogonal signals, etc). TDMA can be understood in layman's terms. Frequency concepts for FDMA should be covered in circuits or linear systems courses.

Comment: @thomas.cloud thanks! I understand TDMA and FDMA in layman's terms but I'm more interested in math topics which would give me rigorous thinking about these concepts just like in that answer

Comment: Some sort of advanced linear systems would probably be helpful too.

Comment: @Krushe Dilip is a "*retired professor of electrical and computer engineering with a lifetime of experience teaching probability and statistics to reluctant engineering undergraduates.*", so one day, in a couple of decades, you might be there too.

Comment: @HarrySvensson so, what is your point?

Comment: Linear algebra is the basis behind linear system and most (linear time-invariant) basic DSP topics/courses.  IIRC, I needed linear algebra even for my undergrad circuits and systems course.

Comment: @Krushe Hmm, I tried to imply that that kind of knowledge will come naturally as you progress through your life and jobs. - I think my comment was a little bit off.